# SSRS - Windows File Share

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report that I am trying to drop in a certain folder on my local machine. The issue is that I run SSRS on our virtual server. Is there a way in the "path" section of the report to have it publish outside of the server? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the File Share subscription, you can have the path be any valid UNC path. As long as you can refer to a drive or folder on your local machine from your VM, it should work fine.

[MS File Share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/file-share-delivery-in-reporting-services?view=sql-server-2017)